# Android Error: Cannot cast from Fragment to ArticleFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am new to Android Programming, currently learning Fragment tutorial from this link:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D88gtGD5bJA
/http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/08/android-development-17/

However, I have encountered an error at this line:

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag =(ArticleFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
```

Error Message: Cannot cast from Fragment to `ArticleFragment`

MainActivity.java:

```
    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout

    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    // If the article fragment is here we're in the two pane layout

    if (articleFrag != null) {

        // Get the ArticleFragment to update itself

        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {

        // If the fragment is not available, use the one pane layout and 
        // swap between the article and headline fragments

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article

        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();

        // The Bundle contains information passed between activities

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        // Save the current article value

        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);

        // Add the article value to the new Fragment

        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        // The FragmentTransaction adds, removes, replaces and
        // defines animations for Fragments
        // The FragmentManager provides methods for interacting
        // beginTransaction() is used to begin any edits of Fragments

        FragmentTransaction transaction = 

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

        // addToBackStack() causes the transaction to be remembered. 
        // It will reverse this operation when it is later popped off 
        // the stack.

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Schedules for the addition of the Fragment to occur

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

news_article.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:baselineAligned="false"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment android:name="com.example.fragment2.HeadlinesFragment"
    android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.fragment2.ArticleFragment"
    android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

Please help me out , I am eager to learn.

Comment: can you shows us your imports and also what your activity extends

Comment: Check your packages. Which class does your ArticleFragment extend? android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   

     HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

Answer (score 0):

In your code import.

`Import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Maybe your code work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think mostly it is because you are mixing the library, as above said, check that you import the right one in your ArticleFragment class

```
Import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```